# FOR XML command works in SQL Server 2008 R2 but not in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2017, for-xml

```
==Edited to include outputs from each server==
==Edited to include additional table definition information==
```

I am attempting to integrate an application running on a SQL 2008R2 database, with a new application that runs on a SQL Server 2017 database.

This is undertaken by SQL scripts that are run as stored procedures on the 2017 database to copy information across from the 2008 database.

The SQL script below works perfectly fine on the 2008R2 database (in management studio 2014) and uses the for XML command to produce a string list of 1's and 0's that correspond to a week that an activity occurs. 1= occurs, 0 =  does not occur, with this script being part of a larger SQL script.

When I run this script within SQL management Studio 17 on a 2017 server with the 2008R2 database setup as a linked server, the script runs but the FOR XML export just returns a sting of 0's and is not working as expected.

I've looked into the For XML command and I am not aware of it acting any differently on different versions on SQL server.

I also have another 10-15 integration scripts (though none of the others use the for xml command), that work perfectly well between the 2008 and 2017 database where the 2008 database is a linked server.

I can individually return the information from the tables via the linked server, but when I attempt to run the query the activity id returns successfully but the code string does not.

I am having to use the for XML script as the old database records each occurrence of an activity as an individual line, while the new system records one record for the activity and then records a string of 0's and 1's that work as a week pattern to say if an activity occurs or not.

I don't know if it is the use of the for xml command itself or the fact that its being run via a linked server.

In the script below I have removed the references for the linked server and the database name for security reasons, but as mentioned the script works perfectly fine in my 2008R2 environment.

When run in 2008 I receive the below output

```
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| activityid |                      code                       |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|      59936 | 11111110111111100000000000000000000000000000000 |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

When Run in 2017 I receive the following output

```
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| activityid |                      code                       |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|      59936 | 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

The *vw_AcademicWeeks* element is a view which picks up the following information

```
 +----------------+-------------+
|     Field      |    Type     |
+----------------+-------------+
| ay_code        | varchar(4)  |
| week_number    | int         |
| ay_start       | date        |
| ay_end         | date        |
+----------------+-------------+
```

This returns for each week within an academic year the start and end date of the week (example shown below)

```
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| ay_code | week_no |  ay_start  |   ay_end   |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|    1718 |       1 | 01/08/2017 | 06/08/2017 |
|    1718 |       2 | 07/08/2017 | 13/08/2017 |
|    1718 |       3 | 14/08/2017 | 20/08/2017 |
|    1718 |       4 | 21/08/2017 | 27/08/2017 |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

The *TT_Activity* table is setup as below

```
+----------------------+-----------+
|      Colum Name      | Data Type |
+----------------------+-----------+
| ActivityOccurrenceID | int       |
| ActivityID           | int       |
| StartTime            | datetime  |
| EndTime              | datetime  |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

This table contains multiple rows for an activity, with different start and end times i.e. if an activity occurs every day at 9am, there would be five entries for a week

```
+----------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ActivityOccurrenceID | ActivityID |      StartTime      |       EndTime       |
+----------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|              2214753 |      65577 | 12/07/2019 13:30:00 | 12/07/2019 14:30:00 |
|              2214752 |      65577 | 05/07/2019 13:30:00 | 05/07/2019 14:30:00 |
|              2214906 |      65583 | 02/07/2019 14:30:00 | 02/07/2019 16:00:00 |
|              2215967 |      65613 | 02/07/2019 14:30:00 | 02/07/2019 16:00:00 |
|              2226569 |      65949 | 02/07/2019 14:30:00 | 02/07/2019 16:00:00 |
|              2226754 |      65963 | 02/07/2019 14:30:00 | 02/07/2019 16:00:00 |
+----------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The *TT_Activity* field contains the basic information for an activity and contains a single record for each activity

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Colum Name  |  Data Type   |
+-------------+--------------+
| ActivityID  | int          |
| Code        | varchar(40)  |
| Description | varchar(255) |
| PeriodID    | int          |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Which contains the following information

```
+------------+---------+-------------+----------+
| ActivityID |  Code   | Description | PeriodID |
+------------+---------+-------------+----------+
|      20668 | Maths   | Maths       |     2017 |
|      20669 | English | English     |     2017 |
|      20670 | Science | Science     |     2017 |
+------------+---------+-------------+----------+
```

==SQL Query Below==

```
select 
tta2.activityid,
  (
    select 
        case when ttao.endtime is null then '0' else '1' end
    from    
        vw_AcademicWeeks aw
        left join 
        TT_ActivityOccurrence ttao 
        on
        (dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, ttao.StartTime)-1), ttao.StartTime)),0)) = aw.ay_start
        and ay_code='1718' 
        and ttao.ActivityID=tta2.ActivityID
    where 
        aw.week_no>=6 
    group by 
        ttao.ActivityID,
        aw.week_no,
        case when ttao.endtime is null then '0' else '1' end
    having 
        count(aw.week_no)<>9
    order by 
        week_no asc
    FOR XML PATH(''))as code



  from
    TT_Activity tta2

    where tta2.PeriodID='2017'
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. You appear to be saying that you run the query in SSMS 2008 and it's fine, but not in SSMS 2017. The version of SSMS you're running the query on won't effect the outcome of the query if you're connected to the same Server. SSMS doesn't effect the way the data engine processes data.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need some details here. This query appears to be fine. Here is a good place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have included the references to the relevant SSMS for clarity. You are correct in that the query works in 2008 but not 2017

Comment: But, like I said, The version of SSMS won't change the results of your query if you're running the same query when connected to the same server. If the results are different on different versions, then you're either running a different query, or connected to a different server.

Comment: I am copying the query from my 2008 instance into my 2017 instance, and I am making no changes to it. The server is set up as a linked server, and my other integration scripts work fine, just this one dosent. I am going to edit the post to show the outputs from 2008 and 2017

Comment: If the 2 queries are different, then incldue both queries, not just one of them.

Comment: the 2 queries are not different, as I have said I have copied the query and made no changes to it

Comment: Are you running both instances of the query against the same instance of the data source?

Comment: How about the table definitions and sample data? See the link I posted 45 minutes ago.

Comment: @EricBrandt, the query is running from the same instance of the data source, the only difference is it being run as a linked server on the 2017 box and directly on the server on the 2008R2 box. I can query the individual tables on the 2017 box and return the results, its just the query that dosent seem to run

Comment: Are you 100% sure the linked server is effectively linking to the proper SQL Server database?

Comment: I can query the tables individually via the linked server and they return all the information that I expect, all my other integration scripts are working fine. Unless there is anything I've missed the linked server seems to be setup correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at the code again and pulling it apart I've found the cause of the issue.

The language of the 2008 R2 server was set as **British**, while the language of the 2017 server was set as **US-English**.

This was causing the vw_AcademicWeeks view to create start and end dates of a week that were wrong, as such the formula string below was returning the incorrect date which was then not matching up.

```
TT_ActivityOccurrence TTAO ON (dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd, - (DATEPART(dw, ttao.StartTime) - 1), ttao.StartTime)), 0)) = aw.ay_start
```